# Django GenericForeignKey fields on multiple models

Tags: python, django

is there a way how I can have GenericForeignKey with fields over two models connected with ForeignKey?

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericForeignKey
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

# Create your models here.

class Main(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField()
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Child(models.Model):
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    main = models.ForeignKey(Main)
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('main__content_type', 'object_id')
```

Comment: You mean that, you want to have a FK to two models?

Comment: No like I have one Main object and bunch of Child objects which all points to Some other model of same type. So to be consistent and do not duplicate tuns of data I would like to store the content_type only once in the main model to which all Child models have to point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to write my own library for it.
https://github.com/BrnoPCmaniak/django-egfk
So now I can do this:

```
class Main(models.Model):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(
        ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)


class Child(models.Model):
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    main = models.ForeignKey(Main, related_name="child")
    content_object = EnhancedGenericForeignKey('main.content_type', 'object_id')
```

Example usage:

```
>>> from test_egfk.models import Main, Child, TestSampleModel
>>> m = Main()
>>> print(m.content_type)
None
>>> m.save()
>>> t = TestSampleModel(text="Test")
>>> t.save()
>>> t.text
'Test'
>>> c = Child(main=m, content_object=t)
>>> c.save()
>>> Main.objects.last().content_type
<ContentType: test sample model>
>>> c.content_object
<TestSampleModel: TestSampleModel object>
```